# How to parse STUN messages from byte array in .net

Tags: c#, .net, stun

I am looking into what it would take to create a STUN server in .Net for a WebRTC project.

I've setup my WebRTC project with a STUN url of localhost and I've got a Socket listening on the same port to try and see what STUN requests look like.

I'm also trying to forward that request to the google STUN url but it doesn't work, but that's not relevant now.

As I'm using C# and .net, I manage to get the STUN request and the data is a byte array.

But the STUN spec mentions working with bits for the different parts of the message.

How do I convert the bytes in the received data to the various parts of a STUN message?
I.E. Message Type, message class, Magic Cookie, transaction Id, etc.

If I convert it to a BitArray, it just contains true/false values.

And the STUN spec mentions things like 0b00, 0b01, which look like HEX values.

Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You could use the precompiled Windows binaries for [Stuntman](http://www.stunprotocol.org) - including stunclient.exe to test your server.  You can reference the source code off of GitHub and consider porting parts of [StunReader](https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver/blob/master/stuncore/stunreader.j) and [StunBuilder](https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver/blob/master/stuncore/stunbuilder.h) to C# or use as a referenced for parsing the binary STUN protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it doesn't look like hex value (0xFF). Those look like a binary values false (0b00) and true (0b01).

Comment: Yes, i realized after a while those are binary and how to parse them.
I'm now able to parse and create the STUN messages. 
Thanks